# Can TRIACs work on 1MHz sine wave?

Tags: power, transistors, analog, power-electronics, power-engineering

[image: short circuit and overload protector[1]]

This is a short circuit and overload protector for 220V 50hz. 
 Does TRIAC also work on 1MHz sine wave?

Comment: No component values and part numbers?

Comment: What do you intend to use this for that would require it to work at 1 MHz?

Comment: AFAIK, there are no 1 MHz TRIACs (or SCRs for that matter) Please check out high frequency triacs on the net. Also if you have selected a particular device, check its datasheet for the maximum frequency and so on. Please ask if you have any doubt on the same.

Comment: Not with any commercially available TRIAC. You might be able to find som super special thyristor which has low enough Qrr to allow some kind of application at 1 MHz and put two in antiparalell, but I doubt it.

Comment: I'm trying to build a current limit to a 1MHz sine source
And I wondered if it could help I just do not have experience in using TRIACs
You may have any idea of how to implement a current limit to a 50-volt 1MHz 0.3A -Sine source

Answer (score 2):

Triacs are "saturating" single "pole" BJT switches that rely on passive sub-threshold current to shut-off the saturating capacitance.

> Thus decay time is too slow to use above 10kHz in most applications and usually much slower! like 120Hz or in your case 100Hz.

Try specifying suitable **low** RdsOn*Coss = "T product" complementary MOSFETs with 5% deadtime min on drivers with suitable rise time.

Keep in mind reactive load decay times of RC=T and R/L=T and consider Zero Valley type switching for PFC.

Comment: Thanks Tony.   

I need to control the voltage source from high current mean add some current detector And active switch like MOSFET or BJT transistor. The voltage source is sine wave voltage source 60V RMS 1MHZ. As this is an AC voltage source current limit is more complex I want to ask any Good concept how to do that?.

Comment: you want to switch on off only or phase and sense current for OCP only or regulated?

Comment: i want to sense current and while OC switch on off.

Comment: next write a spec to include this before you guess at a design. and include every input and output parameter under all conditions